# I don't want the complete article to show on homepage

Tags: posts, pages, admin, homepage

When I post articles the complete article shows in the home page. I just want it to show Intro and then read more. I did not create the site myself and just taking on the role of admin of the page.

Answer (score 1):

For showing limited content , wordpress provides functionality of excerpt. By default excerpt will take upto 50 characters but you can change using wordpress hook.

Gor better understanding you can refer http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt.